# Setting TextView in BaseFragment not working, I'm using view binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I want to set the TextView in BaseFragment (typeface, font size, etc) but it doesn't work.

#### `BaseFragment`

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T> : Fragment() {

    private var viewBinding: ViewBinding? = null
    protected lateinit var todayRequest: TodayRequest
    protected lateinit var mTextView: ZoomTextView
    private var _binding: FragmentTodayBinding? = null;
    private val binding get() = _binding!!;

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentTodayBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

        setConfiguration()
        viewBinding = constructViewBinding()
        viewBinding?.let { init(it) }
        return viewBinding?.root
    }

    private fun setConfiguration() {
        val args: TodayFragmentArgs by navArgs()
        mTextView = _binding!!.include.tvZoomable
        val sp = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val fontSize = sp?.getString("font_size", "18")!!.toFloat()
        val fontFamily = String.format(
            Locale("es"),
            "fonts/%s",
            sp.getString("font_name", "robotoslab_regular.ttf")
        )
        val tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(requireActivity().assets, fontFamily)
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize)
        mTextView.setTypeface(tf)
        val hasInvitatory = sp.getBoolean("invitatorio", false)
        val isVoiceOn = sp.getBoolean("voice", true)
        todayRequest =
            TodayRequest(pickOutDate(), args.hourId, isNightMode(), isVoiceOn, hasInvitatory)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun getViewBinding(): T = viewBinding as T


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewBinding = null
    }

    abstract fun constructViewBinding(): ViewBinding
    abstract fun init(viewBinding: ViewBinding)
}
```

---

#### `TodayFragment`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TodayFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentTodayBinding>() {
    private val mViewModel: TodayViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun constructViewBinding(): ViewBinding = FragmentTodayBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    override fun init(viewBinding: ViewBinding) {
        mViewModel.loadData(todayRequest)
        fetchData()
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                mViewModel.uiState.collect { state ->
                    when (state) {
                        is TodayViewModel.TodayUiState.Loaded -> onLoaded(state.itemState)
                        is TodayViewModel.TodayUiState.Error -> showError(state.message)
                        else -> showLoading()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onLoaded(todayItemUiState: TodayItemUiState) {
        todayItemUiState.run {
            getViewBinding().progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            //getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.text = allData
            mTextView.text = allData
        }
    }

    private fun showLoading() {
        Timber.d("showLoading")
    }

    private fun showError(@StringRes stringRes: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), stringRes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

The problem is in the `onLoaded()` method.

When I put: `mTextView.text = allData`, assuming `mTextView` is the element inheriting from `BaseFragment`, it doesn't show me anything.

And if I put `getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.text = allData` it does show me the data, but the settings I applied to the `TextView` in `BaseFragment` is not reflected (typeFace, font size).

What is wrong in my code and how could I set the `TextView` correctly in `BaseFragment`?

Comment: You don't access child class's views inside the Parent class . that defeats the purpose of Abstraction. your `BaseFragment` Should be a contract only. U can do few common things there like initialize binding and ViewModels ...   And you are also using `val args: TodayFragmentArgs by navArgs()` inside `BaseFragment` which is again create same problem. Do these things inside Child fragment and keep only common stuff inside base.